# replace() function recodes entire column

Tags: r, replace

I am using R, and need to recode some variables in a list. The list is as follows:

```
> list1

Group.1     x
1        4000    
2        3890
```

Where in the `Group.1` column I would like to replace any instance of `1` with `male`, and `2` with `female`.

I have tried to do this with the replace() function:

```
replace(list1,list1$Group.1 == "1", "male")
```

which returns

```
Group.1     x
male        4000    
male        3890
```

i.e., it has also relplaced `Group.1 == 2` with male. Have I missed a step? As far as I can see with my use of the replace function - the `Group.1 == 1` should limit the replace command to values in `Group.1` that equal 1. It seems this criteria is not doing anything.

Comment: Tried `replace(list1,which(list1$Group.1 == "1"), "male")` but still no luck I'm afraid. produces the same behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace` operates on vectors, not data.frames. Try this:

```
> replace(df$Group.1,df$Group.1 == 1, "male")
[1] "male" "2"
```

And to change the data, you can do:

```
> df$Group.1 <- replace(df$Group.1,df$Group.1 == 1, "male")
> df
  Group.1    x
1    male 4000
2       2 3890
```

What you are trying to do looks like a good application for a `factor` column with levels `c("male", "female")`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `mapvalues()`. What you have does not look like a list to me, but a data.frame. Maybe you are thinking of the Python name?

```
#make dataframe
df = data.frame(group.1 = c(1, 2),
                x = c(4000, 3890))

library(plyr)
df$group.1 = mapvalues(df$group.1, c(1, 2), c("Male", "Female"))
df
```

This gives:

```
group.1      x
"Male"    4000
"Female"  3890
```

The benefit of `mapvalues` is that it also works for `NA` values.

Answer (score 0):

A regex replacement using `stringr` would be another approach.

```
list1 <- data.frame(Group.1 = c(1, 2), x = c(4000, 3890) )
list1$Group.1 <- str_replace(list1$Group.1, "1", "male")
list1$Group.1 <- str_replace(list1$Group.1, "2", "female")
list1

  Group.1    x
1    male 4000
2  female 3890
```